# Customize raw_id field query on an inline form

Tags: django, django-admin

How do I customize the spyglass query in an inline form for a raw_id foreignkey?

I tried overriding `formfield_for_foreignkey` but that did nothing and I think it's because it's for dropdown foreignkeys rather than raw_id. I also tried a custom widget but that doesn't seem to work on inline.

Comment: It's a URL in a template, not a query. By default it follows a link to the related model e.g. `https://app.com/admin/myapp/mymodel/?_to_field=id`. What do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of digging around, this is what I came up with.

```
from django.admin import widgets

class ItemSubRecipeRawIdWidget(widgets.ForeignKeyRawIdWidget):
    def url_parameters(self):
        res = super(ItemSubRecipeRawIdWidget, self).url_parameters()
        # DO YOUR CUSTOM FILTERING HERE!
        res['active'] = True  # here I filter on recipe.active==True
        return res

class ItemSubRecipeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        field = super(ItemSubRecipeInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'recipe':
            field.widget = ItemSubRecipeRawIdWidget(rel=ItemSubRecipe._meta.get_field('recipe').rel, admin_site=site)
        return field
```

So the spyglass thing is a `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` and you need to override the default with a custom one. The `url_parameters` function on the widget is what is passed to build the query that populates the list of usable object foreignkeys.

Answer (score 1):

Is enought to do following:

```
class ItemSubRecipeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        field = super(ItemSubRecipeInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'recipe':
            field.widget.rel.limit_choices_to = {'your_field_to_filter': True}
        return field
```